Custom plugin top menu url replace with custom post type list link
How do I alter the position of a Custom Post Type menu item within my plugin admin menu?
I create my custom plugin WPTutor LMS and create one custom post type Course
I want to show my custom plugin top level menu with my custom post type link
We do not need plgin main page

I tyr 'show_ui'  => true,'show_in_menu' => 'wptutorlms' but using this course added under top level menu.
I read some more reference but not successed.
I want this post type as a top level menu

you have to use "show_in_menu" => TRUE when registering the CPT : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

My main menu is add_menu_page(__( 'WpTutor Learning Management System', 'wptutorlms' ),'WPTutor LMS','manage_options','wptutorlms','',$wptutorlms_icon,'55.1); And 'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true, then result is post type menu is separate not in my plugin

You can achieve this by replacing the menu_slug of the main menu (WPTutor LMS) with the "Courses" slug/link. Please see sample snippet below.
Replace the "COURSES_SLUG" with the actual courses slug.
add_menu_page(__( 'WpTutor Learning Management System', 'wptutorlms' ),'WPTutor LMS','manage_options','COURSES_SLUG','',$wptutorlms_icon,'55.1');

As default, custom post type slug is being created with the following format.
edit.php?post_type=courses

After that, you can then hide the first submenu (WPTutor LMS) via CSS as it looks already redundant
#adminmenu .wp-submenu-head {
    display: none;
}

To position sub menus, it can be achieved by utilizing the add_submenu_page() function's position parameter. In this example, since we're aiming to move the courses post type under "WPTutor LMS" main menu, this means that the "Parent menu slug" will be equivalent to the "COURSES_SLUG".
Please see sample snippet below.
add_submenu_page( 'Parent menu slug', 'Page title', 'Menu Title', 'Capability', 'Submenu_slug', 'Callback', 'position - int');

Hope this helps.
